# ¿Quisiera saber si mi consulta tiene registros en MySQL PHP?

Tags: php, mysql

Tengo este código, pero lo que busco es como hacer para saber si el `num_rows` es mayor a 0, necesito ese proceso para poder mandar una notificación push en WS.

```
$stmt= $conn->prepare("select Token from usuariosempleados;");
$stmt->execute();
if($stmt->bind_result($Token)->num_rows > 0)
{
  echo enviarNotificacion($stmt->fetch(), $msj);
}
else {
  echo "-1";
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes realizar lo siguiente

```
/* Esta es la consulta SQL */
        $consulta = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT empr.nombre_empresa
                                        FROM empresa empr
                                       WHERE empr.id_empresa = ?
                                         AND empr.token_empresa = ?");

        /* Comprobamos si la consulta se preparó correctamente */
        if ($consulta === false)
        {
           die('Error SQL: ' . $mysqli->error);
        }

        /*Asignamos al primer "?"*/
        $consulta->bind_param('is', $idEmpresa, $tokenMovimiento);

        /* Comprobamos si la consulta se ejecutó correctamente */
        if ($consulta->execute() === false)
        {
          die('Error SQL: ' . $consulta->error);
        }
        //Asignamos una variable al valor seleccionado desde nuestra consulta, esto si requieres usarla posteriormente, sino puedes obviar esta linea
        $consulta->bind_result($nombreEmpresa);
        /* Aquí obtenemos el registro (si lo hay) */
        if ($consulta->fetch() !== true)
        {
          $resultado['mensaje'] = "No se han encontrado coincidencias";
        }
        else
        {
          $resultado['mensaje'] = "Si ingresa aquí, es porque ha retornado un valor mayor que 0";
        }
        //Imprimimos el valor que ha retornado como $mensaje
        echo json_encode($resultado);
```

Comment: excelente jeocorrales, me funciono :D Gracias

Answer (score 0):

Esto puedes obtenerlo luego de ejecutar la query,

```
$stmt= $conn->prepare("select Token from usuariosempleados;");
$stmt->execute();
//Creamos una variable para almacenar el conteo
$cuenta = $stmt->rowCount();

if($cuenta > 0)
{
  $stmt->bind_result($Token);
  echo enviarNotificacion($stmt->fetch(), $msj);
}
else {
  echo "-1";
}
```

Comment: Me funciono la respuesta anterior bro, gracias :D